# Any thoughts/idea on how to implement a matrix type rule in JBoss Drools

Tags: drools

This is my scenario. A matrix where I have to retrieve a value on the basis of certain inputs in an Excel sheet. See the matrix below. (Our actual matrix is huge. This is for illustration purpose)

```
    # | 10       20      30      40
    -------------------------------------
    0 | 1.00    2.00    3.00    3.00
    1 | 6.00    4.00    4.00    3.00
    2 | 5.00    9.00    5.00    3.00
    3 | 5.00    3.00    5.00    3.00
    4 | 6.00    2.00    5.00    3.00
    5 | 7.00    9.00    6.00    3.00

    So, 
    if input is (0,10) ==> 1
    if input is (3,30) ==> 5 
    if input is (3,20) ==> 3
    if input is (5,20) ==> 9
```

Can someone help me into this, how to implement in drools? By using a drl file or using a Decision table.

My Thoughts:

1. In .drl file, it would not not be a right choice to add multiple "when ... then" rule.
2. Decision table can be a choice. but not sure how effective it would be.

Any suggestions. Sample reference/code would be helpful

Comment: Looks like a `List<Map<Integer,Double>>` to me. Why do you want to complicate matters using rules?

Comment: Reason, if we add the above in java way, business people won't understand as they define business rule depends on the stock/share market condition, let's say and won't be very intuitive to change the matrix. Just wondering, can we do in this way: [link](http://www.deepakgaikwad.net/index.php/2016/05/23/drools-decision-table-tutorial-beginners-using-drools-6-4.html)

Answer (score 0):

The only efficient solution is to use a

```
class Cell {
    int row;
    int col;
    double val;
}
```

to insert all Cell objects and use the rule

```
rule locate
when
    Lookup( $r: r, $c: c ){
    Cell( row == $r, col == $c, $v: val )
then
   ...
end
```

where Lookup is another class where an object is inserted to trigger a lookup for a cell.

Comment: Thanks laune. Not a drool expert, but moving this matrix into the code would defeat the purpose, as we need to add/change (the row, col and value) as per the business condition. Any thoughts?

Comment: The matrix isn't in the code, the matrix is in Cell objects: data!